# Minimum possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(x_i-1)(x_i-2)$ for fixed sum

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose $x$ is a **unknown** sequence of non-negative integers with $n$ elements and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = c$ for a constant $c$.

What is the minimum possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(x_i-1)(x_i-2)$?

I know the answer when we want a lower bound for $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(x_i-1)$. We can expand it and use the *Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality*. But I don't see anything for solving it in this form.

PS: Actually I want a good lower bound over this expression; by good I mean non-trivial ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Updated as per suggestions in the comments.)

I will use
$$
S[x]\equiv \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(x_i-1)(x_i-2).
$$
Obviously, $S[x]\geq 0$.

First, let $n=2$, and set $x_1=c/2+y$ and $x_2=c/2-y$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(x_i-1)(x_i-2)=\frac{(c-2)(12y^2+c(c-4))}{4}.
$$
This means that for $c>2$ the minimum is achieved for the minimal possible value of $|y|$, which is either $0$ or $\pm \tfrac{1}{2}$ depending on whether $c$ is even or odd, which corresponds to $x_1=x_2$ or $x_1=x_2\pm 1$.

Now, consider a general $n>1$. Suppose that there is a pair $i,j$ such that $|x_i-x_j|>1$. Suppose that $x_i+x_j>2$. Then by the above argument, we can alter the values of $x_i,x_j$ while preserving $x_i+x_j$ to make sure that $|x_i-x_j|\leq 1$ and decrease the sum $S[x]$ by doing so. If instead $x_i+x_j\leq 2$, then we must have that $x_i=0$ and $x_j=2$ or vice versa. Therefore, if $x$ achieves the minimum of $S[x]$, then for every pair $i,j$ we have $|x_i-x_j|\leq 1$ or $\{x_i,x_j\}=\{0,2\}$. If the latter option holds for at least one pair $i,j$ then, by the former property, the only other value allowed in the sequence is $1$.

The above argument implies that if a sequence $x$ achieves the minimum of $S[x]$, then one of two options hold:

1. $x_i=a$ or $x_i=a+1$, $\forall i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$, for some integer $a$. (This includes the case when all $x_i$ are identical.)
2. $x_i\in \{0,1,2\}$, $\forall i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$.

The second option can only be realized for $c\leq 2n$ in which case the minimum of $S[x]=0$ can be achieved. For $c>2n$ we need to solve the following problem: let $a\geq 0$ and $0\leq q<n$ be integers such that $(n-q)a+q(a+1)=c$. What is the minimal value of $S(q,a)=(n-q)a(a-1)(a-2)+q(a+1)a(a-1)$? (We can assume that $q<n$ since $q=n$ is equivalent to $q=0$ with $a$ replaced by $a+1$.)

The condition $(n-q)a+q(a+1)=c$ is equivalent to $na+q=c$, which uniquely determines $a=\lfloor c/n\rfloor$ and $q=c-na$, which in turn uniquely fixes the value of $S(q,a)$ which gives the tight lower bound.

Comment: Nice answer. We can rearrange the expression to find minima of $\sum_i y_i^3$, $y_i=x_i-1\geq-1$ subject to the conditions $\sum_i y_i=c'=c-n$ and then use Lagrange multiplier method for real continuum to get that it is minimum when $y_i=c'/n$. So, for integer case the behaviour should be close to uniform, that you've found.

Comment: instead of specific calculations, it could be observed that $f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$ is convex on $[2,\infty), that yields the same property immediately

Comment: There is no case analysis. If $c=an+q $ with $q\leq n$ then $a = \lfloor c/n\rfloor$ and $q = c - n \lfloor c/n \rfloor $ by long division so the minimum value is $n \lfloor c/n\rfloor (\lfloor c/n\rfloor-1) (\lfloor c/n\rfloor-2) + 3 (c - n \lfloor c/n\rfloor) \lfloor c/n\rfloor (\lfloor c/n\rfloor-1) $.

Comment: @WillSawin good point, was in a bit of a rush. Updated accordingly.

Comment: @FedorPetrov perhaps I'm being slow, but how do you see that $f(x)$ is convex? (Obviously I can prove it, but your comment seems to imply that there is a way to show this without a calculation.)

Comment: Any polynomial with all roots real and positive leading coefficient is increasing and convex after the last root. This follows from Rolle theorem, for example (the roots of the second derivative are also real and between the roots of the original polynomial)