# Minimum possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{x_i}{r}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose an **unknown** sequence $x$ with $n$ non-negative integers such that the sum of elements of that is fixed. In other words $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = c$ for some constant $c$.

What is the minimum possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{x_i}{r}$ for some fixed $r$.

PS: I want a non-trivial lower-bound.

UPD: If you have a recursive function it's also OK.

Comment: Hi. This question looks a great deal like this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443310/minimum-possible-value-of-sum-i-1n-x-ix-i-1x-i-2-for-fixed-sum. If you're the same author, you may wish to request a merging of your accounts. Observe though that it'd be preferable to have a little bit more context in order to motivate people to try to answer it.

Comment: How do we interpret $x_i$ choose $r$ if $x_i<r$?  (Or do you want to add an additional assumption that $x_i\geq r$?)

Comment: @BillBradley : I think the standard convention is that $\binom xr=0$ if $x$ and $r$ are integers such that $r\ge0$ and $x<r$. This also follows from the combinatorial definition of $\binom xr$ as the number of subsets of cardinality $r$ of a set of cardinality $x$.

Answer (score 4):

For any natural $r$, the function $f_r$ given by the formula
$$f_r(x):=\frac1{r!}\,\prod_{j=0}^{r-1}\max(0,x-j)$$
for real $x$ is convex. So, by a [standard majorization argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization#Equivalent_conditions) (see the sentence "For every convex function
$h:{\mathbb  {R}}\to {\mathbb  {R}}$,
$\sum _{i=1}^{d}h(x_{i})\geq \sum _{i=1}^{d}h(y_{i})$." there),
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f_r(x_i)\ge L:=L_{c,n,r}:=nf_r(c/n)$$
for all real $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=c$.

Since $\binom xr=f_r(x)$ for any nonnegative integer $x$, we see that $L=nf_r(c/n)$ is the nontrivial lower bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{x_i}r$ for all nonnegative integers $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=c$, as desired.

This lower bound is exact in the sense that it is attained when $c/n$ is a nonnegative integer and $x_i=c/n$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.

---

**Update:** This majorization argument also implies the lower bound
$$l:=l_{c,n,r}:=k\binom{a+1}r + (n-k)\binom ar$$
with $a:=a_{c,n}:=\lfloor c/n\rfloor$ and $k:=k_{c,n}:=c-na_{c,n}$,
given in [Will Sawin's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443327/36721) (in a slightly different form) . The lower bound $l[\ge L]$ is a bit more complicated than $L$ but exact even when $c/n$ is not a nonnegative integer.

Answer (score 3):

[Again](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443313/18060) a discrete convexity argument gives a lower bound of $$n \binom{ \lfloor c/n \rfloor}{r} + ( c - n \lfloor c/n\rfloor ) \binom{ \lfloor c/n \rfloor}{r-1}.$$

This is because raising $x_i$ by $1$ and lowering $x_j$ by $1$ always reduces the sum or keeps it constant if $x_i> x_j$ since we have $$\binom{x_i}{r}  + \binom{x_j}{r} - \binom{x_i-1}{r} - \binom{x_j+1}{r} = \binom{x_i-1}{r-1} - \binom{x_j}{r-1} \geq 0.$$

Making this change decreases $\sum_i x_i^2$ unless $x_i = x_j+1$. We can iterate this process until it is no longer possible to reduce $\sum_i x_i^2$, in which case we must have $\max_{i,j} |x_i-x_j| \leq 1$.

When this happens, the $x_i$ must consist of $\lfloor c/n \rfloor$ with multiplicity $n- ( c - n \lfloor c/n\rfloor ) $ and $\lfloor c/n\rfloor+1$ with multiplicity $c - n \lfloor c/n\rfloor $, giving the stated lower bound.